# SQL Server RODBC Connection

Tags: r, rodbc

Does anyone have a connection string example for using RODBC and connecting to MS SQL Server 2005 or 2008.

Thank you.

Comment: Most connection string questions can be answered at [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=mysqlhost;database=mydbname;trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables')
```

Comment: I'm trying this but  am getting error "SQL Server does not exist or access denied." Do you have to enter a username/password? Also I have a dsn on my remote site but this does not seem to be mentioned. The RODBC docs were not all that clear to me

Comment: The example uses the option "trusted_connection=true" for automatic windows authentication. You can also provide username=... and password=... as parameters in the connection string.

Comment: actually for me `username` and `password` did not work - i had to provide the parameters `uid=...;` and `pwd=...;`.

Comment: Any ideas how to obtain column names from the DW into R?

Comment: NOTE I had to use the IPV6 Ip address instead of the server name to get this to work.

Comment: Just for what it's worth, if you are familiar with the `DBI` interface, the newer [`odbc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) package is DBI-compliant and an alternative to the `RODBC` package.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from [a posting to r-help](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2010-February/227555.html):

```
 library(RODBC)
 channel <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server;server=01wh155073")
 initdata<- sqlQuery(channel,paste("select * from  test_DB .. 
 test_vikrant"))
 dim(initdata)
 odbcClose(channel)
```

Comment: How would you do this from Mac OSX?  Same way?  Is that possible, with the windows login requirement?

Comment: Seems unlikely this would work using same machine with MS's SQL Server on a Mac, but with some sort of remote access terminal arrangement, perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

**If you have to include the USERNAME and PASSWORD:**

```
library(RODBC) # don't forget to install it beforehand

my_server="ABC05"
my_db="myDatabaseName"
my_username="JohnDoe"
my_pwd="mVwpR55zobUldrdtXqeHez"


db <- odbcDriverConnect(paste0("DRIVER={SQL Server};
                                 server=",my_server,";
                                 database=",my_db,";
                                 uid=",my_username,";
                                 pwd=",my_pwd))


sql="SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTableName" #dbo is the schema here
df <- sqlQuery(db,sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RSQLS package: https://github.com/martinkabe/RSQLS

Very fast pushes data from data.frame to SQL Server or pulls from SQL Server to data.frame.

**Example:**

```
library(devtools)
install_github("martinkabe/RSQLS")
library(RSQLS)

cs <- set_connString("LAPTOP-USER\\SQLEXPRESS", "Database_Name")
push_data(cs, dataFrame, "dbo.TableName", append = TRUE, showprogress = TRUE)
df <- pull_data(cs, "SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName", showprogress = TRUE)
```

This solution is much faster and more robust than **RODBC::sqlSave** or **DBI::dbWriteTable**.

Answer (score 0):

**First You have to Create/configure DSN (ODBC connection with specific DB)**

Then install `RODBC` library.

```
library(RODBC)
myconn <-odbcConnect("MyDSN", uid="***", pwd="*******")

fetchData<- sqlQuery(myconn, "select * from tableName")
View(fetchData)
close(myconn)
```