# unable to connect to azure vm database from R

Tags: sql-server, r, azure, rodbc

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database running on a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure, from R.

Here is what my SQL server looks like
[image]

This is my connection string

```
library(RODBC)
channel = odbcConnect(dsn="something.cloudapp.net",uid="myusername",pwd="mypassword");
```

However, I keep getting this error

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=servername.cloudapp.net,1433;UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=servername.cloudapp.net,1433;UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword"):
  ODBC connection failed
```

Why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Have you [created a dsn](https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/data/v76/help/windows%20dsn.aspx) as RODBC, as far as I have used it, requires a defined dsn to login. I created it as a system dsn for what I do and it works for me. You do require admin to perform this task.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the more flexible [`odbcDriverConnect`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rodbc/docs/odbcConnect) function like this:

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;')
```

Here it is with carriage returns for readability:

```
odbcDriverConnect(
    'driver={SQL Server};
     Server=myServerAddress;
     Database=myDataBase;
     User Id=myUsername;
     Password=myPassword;')
```

See also:

- [SQL Server RODBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720508/sql-server-rodbc-connection)
- http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
- http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rodbc/docs/odbcConnect