# Connect R to a SQL Server database engine

Tags: sql-server, r, pentaho

At my work I have R-Studio (Microsoft R Open 3.2.5) installed and would like to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database, to run scripts using the tables I have.

Is there any chance that I can connect to a SQL Server database using Pentaho and then using the object Execute R-Script to make an OLAP Cube? 
Do I need a package to connect SQL engine?
What would be the steps to perform?

I already have the snowflake arquitectura of the data base. With the fact table and the state tables. But I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can connect to SQL Server directly from R using at least 4 libraries ([RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720508/sql-server-rodbc-connection), [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver), [RSQLServer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLServer/index.html), [RJDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html)).

As long as you have enough RAM, you can import your data into R and do your analysis there using for example amazing [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html) or [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) packages. On the other hand, you can just connect to SQL Server and send SQL queries to the server and do your data wrangling inside your database and then import results to R for further (statistical) analysis and visualization.

Comment: As of Feb 2019, the author of RSQLServer recommends using the odbc package. Here's the archive of RSQLServer: https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer and here in the link to the odbc package: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc

Comment: Can you use these drivers with R Studio Free or do you need R Studio Pro to do it?

Comment: You can use the free version.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this should work:

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=YourDBName\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=TestDB;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(dbconnection)
```

Check out these links:

[RODBC odbcDriverConnect() Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420999/rodbc-odbcdriverconnect-connection-error)

https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/connect-r-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/

Finally, make sure SQL Server has all proper permissions applied.

Comment: shouldn't it be `odbcClose(dbconnection )`

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to connect to SQL Server, using Windows creds.

```
library("RODBC")
#library("XLConnect")

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=Name_Of_Server;database=Name_Of_DB;trusted_connection=true')
currTableSQL<-paste("SELECT * From Your_Table",sep="")
currTableDF<-sqlQuery(dbhandle,currTableSQL)
```

Uncomment the XLConnect if you want to utilize that library.  I feel like a lot of times if you are using SQL Server, you are using Excel as well.

Comment: Are there any security issues if we establish a oracle DB connection to R? Like data getting stolen, etc. How secure is this method?

Comment: @xkcvk2511 check with your vendor. The connection is only as secure as the database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has had native support for calling R programs since SQL Server 2016. So besides calling SQL Server from R scripts like others here have suggested, you can put R scripts into SQL Server and get native scalable functionality, particularly for machine learning.