# "Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'srv-sql2008' (0)" between R and MySQL server

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I need to connect the sql server databases to R. 
I tried many times and I search I find many methods here 
[Connect R to a SQL Server database engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401230/connect-r-to-a-sql-server-database-engine). But It doesn't work

So  I search more and I find this one https://mkmanu.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/r-and-mysql-a-tutorial-for-beginners/

I just follow the first step:

```
library(RMySQL)

mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='manoj', password='password', host='localhost')
```

But this error was shown:

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'srv-sql2008' (0)

How can I resolve this please?

Comment: do you want to connect mysql or mssql ?

Comment: @SerkanArslan, i want to connect to mysql