# SQL Server 2014 RODBC Connection

Tags: r, rodbc

Does anyone have a connection string example for using RODBC and connecting to MS SQL Server 2014.

If I use below connection string works fine for SQL Server 2008 but not for 2014

```
library(RODBC)  

connectionstring <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=Serveraname\\Instance name,PortNumber;database=database name;uid=username;pwd=password;')
```

Comment: Do you already know a solution (please post it here then)? What is the error message you get?

Comment: Possible a duplicate or answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720508/sql-server-rodbc-connection

Answer (score 0):

Is it the `Instance name`? On SQL server 2014 you do not need an instance name AFAIK. 
I suggest you use the Native Client driver. It usually works fine with 2014 SQL servers.