# Import dataframe from SQL Server into R

Tags: r, sql-server

I have a working R script. Now, I extract the data from the SQL server into an Excel Sheet and import this Excel sheet into R. 
I would like to import directly from the SQL Server. 
The data I have:

- DNS
- Database
- Login
- Password

Is this enough to extract the database from this SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is enough. You can benefit from RODBC library like below:

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL 
Server};server=mysqlhost;database=mydbname;trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables')
```

Ref: [SQL Server RODBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720508/sql-server-rodbc-connection)

EDIT: For your case, you can try:

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL 
Server};server=mysqlhost;database=mydbname;uid=yourusername;pwd=yourpassword')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from information_schema.tables')
```

Ref: https://blog.learningtree.com/querying-sql-server-data-from-r-using-rodbc/

Comment: The `dbhandle` gives an error:
`Error: State 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL-server doesn't exist or access is denied.`

Comment: Make sure you give the correct server and database names, and you have rights to access the db and the table

Comment: `dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=DNS;database=DBNAME;trusted_connection=true')` is my entry in the console. But where do I give the login and password?

Comment: @George ... `trusted_connection` should be replacement of user/password. Also a DSN (not DNS) is not replacement of server but replacement of driver.  In fact, DSNs can contain server/database/user information. Hence, you would use: `odbcConnect('DSN')`. This avoids exposing DB credentials and specs in code.

Comment: So what should I replace driver with?