# Accessing tables inside connections database in R

Tags: r, odbc, tidyverse

I am using this code to connect

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)


con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SQLSERVERR") # Can't use this

con1 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SQLSERVERR",database = "db1")
con2 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SQLSERVERR",database = "db2")

tbx <- tbl(con1,"some_table")
```

But my connection has tables inside databases and I  would like to send sql queries to them using dplyr.

something like

```
tbx <- tbl(con, db = "db1", "some_table")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is very broad, and seems like you're looking more for a tutorial than help with a specific code question. There is pretty [extensive guidance](https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/) I'd recommend starting with on databases with `dplyr`

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on a few things. I had the best luck doing a similar task using the RODBC package. [SQL Server RODBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720508/sql-server-rodbc-connection)
I could access views within the database this way using the `sqlFetch` function but it is possible to do the query within the `sqlQuery` function as shown in the example.  If you're accessing a secure, live database, you may want to try the `odbcConnect` function (also within the same package), having added it as a datasource (https://turbofuture.com/computers/Connect-to-SQL-Server-from-R).